# Controlling SAM function log-group creation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

When using CloudFormation with SAM, and creating a SAM function - a log group for that lambda may or may not be created.

The existence of the log group when the SAM function resources have entered the `CREATE_COMPLETE` state depends on the configuration of the lambda (e.g. if provisioned concurrency is set) and/or other things that are not controlled by the CloudFormation template (e.g. a lambda with the same name was previously created and ran, etc)

In a nested stack (or another dependent resource), I need that log group in order to create a subscription for it - but creating it if it already exists leads to a failure.

Creating a new log group with a different and unique name does not help as there is no way to control to which log group a lambda will log (it will always log to a log group with its own name).

Is there a way to ensure the existence of the log group with a certain name, but without failing the stack when it already exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [CloudFormation Macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to perform the verification and then return the appropriate template for the log group back to CloudFormation.